# Wordpress Rest API 405 error unable to save Gutenberg widgets

Tags: wordpress, rest, wordpress-gutenberg

I am getting a "response is not a valid json response" error when trying to save Block widgets. I have tried everything I can think of; reset permalinks, deactivated all plugins, reset to a default theme (TwentyTwenty-One), and deleted all widgets, but get the same

```
{"code":"rest_no_route","message":"No route was found matching the URL and request method.","data":{"status":404}}
```

error when checking in Inspect. Tried in Edge and Chrome.
Using Ubuntu 20.04 and PHP 7.4.3 with WP 6.0, although it was happening in previous WP versions. Nothing unusual in wp-config.php, and nothing in sites-enabled that I can see. I do have multiple wordpress instances (3 total) running on the server.
Saving a post in the block editor works fine, it's only in trying to save widgets.
It's either something in the database(s), or something in Nginx, probably, but I'm hitting a wall. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have solved this - at some point I had added this line to the sites-enabled nginx config:
" if ($request_method !~ ^(GET|HEAD|POST)$ ) {return 405;}"
...probably due to a step by step now long lost on how to secure WP on Nginx. I commented out the rule and saving widgets (finally, after about a million tries) worked.